# How to write to response from HTTP Client Node.JS

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following...

```
var request = require('request');

exports.list = function(req, res){
  res.send("Listing");
};
exports.get = function(req, res){
  request.get("<URL>", function (err, res, body) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(body,"utf8");
    }
  });
};
```

This fails with the following....

```
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'send'
```

How do I do this?

**UPDATE** tried to use write instead of send but...

```
/Users/me/Development/htp/routes/property.js:9
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      ^
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'setHeader'
```

Also writing out to the console instead works fine.

Comment: Need more information on your query to answer ..... Usage Express framework could be possible solution ..... it makes the work a lot easier

Comment: What are you using this function for ? `res.send` is from express API. Are you using that ?

Comment: I am using express, I will try using the commands for non-express as listed below and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with scope of variables, my response output was the same name as the response object I got back in my callback. Changing this around (resp vs res) made it work....

```
exports.get = function(req, res){
  request.get("<url>", function (err, resp, body) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: are you using express? the response object passed to the `http.createServer()` callback function, does not have a `req.send()` method, afaik `req.send` is added by Express. congrats on solving your problem!

Comment: As stated in other comments yes I am using express. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, is to make Request > Response server. But you are using Request module, that allows to get stuff rather than respond.

What you need is `http` or better get [express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) and use it, as it is straight forward and well popular web framework for exactly what you need.

Comment: See my answer it had nothing to do with the framework, I am extremely familiar with express and have used it on multiple projects. The problem was variables hiding each other.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware OP is using Express. You will encounter a similar error if you attempt to use `req.send` with the vanilla HTTP module instead of Express.

```
var http = require('http');    
function requestHandler(req, res){
  //res.send(200, '<html></html>'); // not a valid method without express
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('<html><body>foo bar</body></html>');
};
http.createServer(handler).listen(3000);
```

Comment: You should elaborate more on your answer.